# If f uniformly continous then $|f(x)|\leq C\cdot (1+|x|)$ for constant C

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let f: $\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ be an uniformly continuous function.
Show that there is a constant $C$ with $|f(x)|\leq  C\cdot (1+|x|)$.

I can´t seem to find the right idea to solve this problem.
Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: There isn't, what if you take a uniformly continuous function with $f(0)\neq 0$?

Comment: Don't you mean $|f(x)|\leq c(1+|x|)$?

Comment: Yes indeed, it was early in the morning for me as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that you would like to show the inequality:
$|f(x)|\leq c(1+|x|)$ (see Mathematician 42's comment).

Since $f$ is uniformly continuous then for $\epsilon>0$ there is $\delta>0$ such that for $|x-y|\leq\delta$,  $|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$.

Let $x\not=0$, and take the smallest positive integer $n$ such that  $|x|/n<\delta$.
Then for $x_i=\frac{ix}{n}$ with $i=1,\dots,n$,
$$|f(x)|\leq |f(0)|+|f(x_1)-f(0)|+|f(x_2)-f(x_1)|+\dots+|f(x_n)-f(x_{n-1})|<|f(0)|+n\epsilon.$$
If $|x|>\delta$ then $n\geq 2$ and $|x|/(n-1)\geq \delta$ which implies that $n\leq \frac{|x|}{\delta}+1$. Hence
$$|f(x)|<|f(0)|+n\epsilon\leq |f(0)|+\left(\frac{|x|}{\delta}+1\right)\epsilon.$$
If $|x|\leq \delta$ then $n=1$ and
$$|f(x)|<|f(0)|+|f(x)-f(0)|<|f(0)|+\epsilon.$$

Hence we have that for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$,
$$|f(x)|< |f(0)|+\left(\frac{|x|}{\delta}+1\right)\epsilon\leq C(1+|x|)$$
where
$$C=\max\left(\frac{\epsilon}{\delta},|f(0)|+\epsilon\right).$$

Comment: It's early in the morning for me, but I'm fairly certain that the condition the OP posted is different. If I plug in $x=0$, it yields $|f(0)|=0$ which is certainly not true for all uniformly continuous functions.

Comment: @Mathematician 42 Yes you are right. It should be something like $|f(x)|\leq c(1+|x|)$.

Comment: Yup, that would be a useful exercise.

Comment: thank you very much, it was early in the morning for me as well and indeed the exercise was supposed to be the now edited. But I am a little confused by your hint. Is it really necessary to size up f(0)?

Comment: @user335236 $0$ is just point you can change it and modify the proof.

Comment: @user335236 I edited my answer and I completed the proof. Any more doubts?

Comment: The proof is totaly clear and I see that it is possible to "construct" the proof around a different point than 0, but why do we make it "complicated" and don't just say that |f (0)|=M?

Comment: @user335236 I separated the case $n=1$. Let me think...

Comment: @user335236 You are right. See my edited answer. Note that we can take  $\epsilon=1$.