# Let $f : [0, +\infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be uniformly continuous. Show that $f$ has sublinear growth

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f : [0, +\infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be uniformly continuous. Show that $f$ has sublinear growth

I need to show that there exists $A,B > 0$ such that |$f(x)| ≤ Ax + B$, for all $x ≥ 0$

I was thinking of using the definition of uniform continuity for $\epsilon = 1$ to show that all the values of $x \in [0, +\infty)$ are obtained in tiny steps without changing the value of $f$ much.

Comment: Take a look to my answer here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1961828/if-f-uniformly-continous-then-fx-leq-c-cdot-1x-for-constant-c/1961840#1961840